# C- programming array assignment issues

Tags: c, arrays, loops

I am doing this program for an assignment. The code is to decrypt a ciphertext based on the frequency of letters in the text. The problem arises when I am trying to change the ciphertext letter to its plaintext letter. For some reason the ciphertext letter is changed to a random letter.

I tried to see what was wrong so I added print statement to the code that does the swap. I noticed that for each letter, the code swaps it two times before making its last assignment.  here is a snippet of the code:

```
//decryption
for (j = 0, k = strlen(cipher); j < k; j++) {


    for (c = 0 ; c < 26; c++){


       if (cipher[j] == freqCounts[c].letter){//checks if the ciphertext letters match

              //use the following line of code to see how the swap is being handled
               /* 
               printf("f[%d] = %c and c[%d] =  %c\n", c, freqCounts[c].pletter, j, cipher[j]);
               */
        cipher[j] = freqCounts[c].pletter;//swaps with plaintext letter here

           }
        }
   }
```

Could you please provide with some insight as to why it's making the additional swaps per letter.

Comment: I see no swapping, only plain assignment.

Comment: When it goes through that bit of code additional assignments occur.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that `freqCounts[0].letter=='a'`, `freqCountes[0].pletter=='b'`, `freqCountes[1].letter=='b'`.

In this case, `cipher[j] == freqCounts[c].letter` becomes true at `c=0`, and it becomes true again at `c=1`.

I think adding `break;` after `cipher[j] = freqCounts[c].pletter;` may work.